# L shaped custom gallery view

Tags: android

I want to implement a gallery view in which the gallery is L-shaped and the thumbnails move from vertical to horizontal. And also: the image size will be max at the center and will decrease from center to last.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Good luck! [FAQ here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Thnx for the compliment.But should i start with custom gallery view or anything else

Comment: I think this question is **related**...
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8352581/1089811